# Get call status twilio php

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I want to get current call status.How can i do this currently here is my code

```
$dial = $response->dial(
    array(
        'record' => True,
        'recordingStatusCallback' => "testing.php",
        'action' => "conference.php",
       'method' => 'POST'
    )
);
```

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#attributes-recording-status-callback-event

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : yes but not worked

Comment: So where's the status callback code? Also, you can set `recordingStatusCallbackEvent`, deciding on what events you want to callback to be triggered. And what does _"not work"_ mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: i getting error "" Attribute 'StatusCallbackEvent' is not allowed to appear in element 'Dial'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the comments I can see you want to use `StatusCallback` and `StatusCallbackEvent`. Those attributes aren't available on the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) verb directly.

You can use those attributes with [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number), [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) and [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip) though. So, for example, with `<Number>` you should define your `<Dial>` like this:

```
$dial = $response->dial(
    array(
        'record' => True,
        'recordingStatusCallback' => "testing.php",
        'action' => "conference.php",
       'method' => 'POST'
    )
);
$dial->number($to,
  array(
    'statusCallbackEvent' => 'initiated ringing answered completed',
    'statusCallback' => 'https://myapp.com/calls/events',
    'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST'
  )
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: after getting callback status how can we put call on hold if call status is in progress ? and after first call completed how can we connect second call ?

Comment: That sounds like a completely new question and Stack Overflow comments are not the best place to answer detailed follow ups like that. Can you start a new question showing what you've tried and what is not working?